# With SSIS, the flat file connection manager messes up with csv files having "," in values in the range of thousands

Tags: csv, ssis

I had data in a CSV file, which appears in a notepad something like this:

[image]

In SSIS, when I try to load this file in a Delimited format, the data which appears in the preview gets messed up due to the commas which occur in the numeric values, eg. in thousands and millions. The data looks something like this:

[image]

Is there any way in which this problem can be taken care of in the connection manager itself ?

Thanks!

Comment: When setting up the source, did you setup text-qualifiers (ie, `"` in the above case)?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newbie, workign in SSIS  for the first time. Got it now though. Thank you ! :)

Comment: No need to apologize -- I had encountered a similiar issue my first time working with SSIS, we all have to start somewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Text Qualifier` as shown here:

[image]

This will take care of the columns that have quotes inside.  Sometimes it gets really bad with CSV data, and I've had to resort to script components doing some cleanup, but that's really rare.